# Unable to configure plugins: (ArgumentError) Cannot determine timezone from nil - Logstash

Tags: oracle, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I am trying to move data from my Oracle database to Elasticserach via Logstash. I get this timezone error whenever i try to run logstash.
`bin/logstash -f D:\\ElasticSearch\\logstash-8.10.2\\config\\oracle-config.conf`
Error:

```
[2023-10-23T09:13:35,247][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException", :message=>"Unable to configure plugins: (ArgumentError) Cannot determine 
timezone from nil\n(secs:1698027213.249,utc~:\"2023-10-23 02:13:33.24900007247924805\",ltz~:nil)\n(etz:nil,tnz:\"ICT\",tziv:\"2.0.6\",tzidv:\"1.2023.3\",rv:\"3.1.0\",rp:\"java\",win:true,rorv:nil,astz:nil,eov:\"1.2.7\",eotnz:\"???\",eotnfz:\"???\",eotlzn:\"???\",\ndebian:nil,centos:nil,osx:nil)\nTry setting `ENV['TZ'] = 'Continent/City'` in your script (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)", :backtrace=>["org.logstash.config.ir.CompiledPipeline.<init>(CompiledPipeline.java:120)", "org.logstash.execution.AbstractPipelineExt.initialize(AbstractPipelineExt.java:186)"
```

This is my logstash config

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[my_ip]/[my_service]"
    jdbc_default_timezone => "Asia/Jakarta" //my timezone: UTC:+7
    jdbc_user => "[my_user]"
    jdbc_password => "******"
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:/Users/kynk/Downloads/jdbc/lib/ojdbc8.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    statement => "SELECT *
                  from mb_config_cross_sell;"
  }
}
output {
    stdout{
    codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

I also try to search and try those thread
[thread_1](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-doesnt-work-in-windows-correctly-please-help/323161/2)
[thread_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76945497/unable-to-configure-plugins-argumenterror-cannot-determine-timezone-from-nil)
and more...
but the result is the same (Cannot determine timezone from nil)
Anyone can shred some light? Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting an environment variable TZ as it was suggested in the error message?

Comment: Yes, i have just try it.
1. set ENV in filter
filter {
  environment {
    add_field => { "TZ" => "Asia/Jakarta" }
  }
}
2. set ENV in windows variables: in system variables
 Name: TZ value: Asia/Jakarta

Comment: Have you fully shut down the terminal window after setting the  system variables?

Comment: After reset machine it's work. Thank you.